# Changing the content view

Tags: java, android, android-mapview

In my application, based on a `MapActivity`, I want to use different content views. One is a Google map view and the others are "standard" views.

My problem is simple :

- I start with the map view using `setContentView(R.layout.myMapView)` : OK
- I switch to another view with `setContentView(R.layout.myOtherView)` : OK
- I go back to the map view, again using `setContentView(R.layout.myMapView)` : the application crashes.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.

Comment: Ideally setContentView should be only called once for an activity. A lot of depend on it. Such as 'findViewById' checks the views inside the layout for the activity. If you keep switching the layouts these can cause errors. Its better to continue with multiple activites with their own layouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using two different layouts with only one activity? Why don't you use two different activities each based on one single layout?

I think it would be easier to handle.

Comment: It seems a good idea. But I don't want my activities to be pushed in the back stack, i.e I want the "back" key to close the whole application and not only the last launched activity. Is it possible?

Comment: it is. Just open the second activity with the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Comment: Well, in fact, the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP doesn't do what I want. After reading the developer's guide about tasks and activities, I come to the conclusion that it is not possible to have the back key closing each and every activity present in the task.

Comment: hmmm I'm not following you. when you open a new activity with this flag, it will clear the activity stack and fire the new one. pressing the back key will then close the app.

Answer (score 0):

can comment if you put more details here but usually when switching views inside same activity 
a careless call to findviewbyid() can create null pointer exceptions

eg 
after  `setContentView(R.layout.myOtherView)`
if program tries to find a view actually present in `R.layout.myMapView` you get a null pointer